# Print to command line

Tags: command-line

I use bash 4.4.

How do I print the a file to command line.

For example,

```
$ printf "HELLO" > file
$ my-command file
$ HELLO
```

where the `HELLO` in the last line shows after the second command is run.

A similar method is

```
$ history
1 ls
2 cd ~
$ !2:p
$ cd ~
```

which will show the historical command in the next command line without executing it.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? `cat FILE` to print the content of a file to command line? Is that what you meant? or might be a good idea to clarify the title and elaborate the question a little bit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can bash write to its own input stream?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/213799)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yeah, I cannot find a proper keyword for this kind of question. Thank you.